# Web Service Invocation

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I would like to invoke a web service trough my Java EE application and set a parameter to the URL. the web service is deployed in a Tomcat local server, and the application in another one.
here are the steps I did :

1) Open a connection to the Web Service using this :

```
String myParam;
urlServlet = "http://localhost:8084/myWebService";
url = new URL(urlServlet);
urlConnection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
```

2) set the parameter :

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", myParam.length() + "");
outstream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(outstream);
outputStream.write(myParam);
outputStream.flush();
```

The problem is that this code doesn't bring the result that i'm looking for. anybody knows where did I failed ? or how should I do to fix this ? Thank you all

Comment: What is `myParam`? It should be of the form `myparameterkey=myparametervalue`

Comment: it's an object. i just putted here a String for the example. my object does actually have a value

Comment: Does its `toString()` method return a string in the format `key=value`?

Comment: yes, it does. it's actually a DOT script that i want to pass to the WebService so it will generate the graph for this DOT dource.